# How to Create New Image From Array List Which Contains Binary Pixel Data

Tags: python, image, arraylist, binary, python-imaging-library

Here I use the PIL Library to read and manipulate images. I am confused, how to create a new image from the list of arrays containing binary pixel data, after being converted to binary images.

I have tried it, but the resulting image is of type RGB, not a binary image. The following is the code that I wrote:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('data_train/ga.jpeg')

pixels = img.load()

width, height = img.size

all_pixels = []

for x in range(width):

    for y in range(height):
        hpixel = pixels[x, y]
        img_gray = (0.2989 * hpixel[0]) + (0.5870 * hpixel[1]) + (0.1140 * hpixel[2])

        if img_gray >= 110:
            all_pixels.append('1')
        else:
            all_pixels.append('0')

data_isi = {'0': 0,

            '1': 255}

data = [data_isi[letter] for letter in all_pixels]

img_new = Image.fromarray(data)

img_new.save('data_train/gabiner.jpeg')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use proper formatting for your code. In current format, your code is broken into multiple bits and pieces.

Comment: How can I use the right format for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

As you are required to use a `for` loop, you could go with something more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image and get dimensions
img = Image.open('start.jpg').convert('RGB')
width, height = img.size

# Actually load input pixels, else PIL is too lazy
imi = img.load()

# List of result pixels
imo = []

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        R, G, B = imi[x, y]
        gray = (0.2989 * R) + (0.5870 * G) + (0.1140 * B)

        if gray >= 110:
            imo.append(255)
        else:
            imo.append(0)

# Make output image and put output pixels into it
result = Image.new('L', (width,height))
result.putdata(imo)

# Save result
result.save('result.png')
```

Which turns this start image:

[image]

Into this result:

[image]

**Original Answer**

You appear to be converting the image to greyscale and thresholding at 110, which can be done much more simply, and faster, like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image and make greyscale
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')

# Threshold to make black and white
thr = im.point(lambda p: p > 110 and 255)

# Save result
thr.save('result.png')
```

Comment: thank you, but I was asked by my lecturer to make code to manipulate pixels directly, so I need a reference on how to manipulate pixels directly, to be able to make grayscale images. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I have forced myself to use some `for` loops - please have another look.

Comment: How to  save image into single channel color in PIL?

Comment: Like I did. Create the image as single channel `Image.new('L',...)` then `save()`